# ¿cómo hacer funcionar graphiql-rails para producción en Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, graphql

actualmente hice un  deploy de una app con rails + graphql a heroku, si bien en local la url `localhost:3000/graphiql` me funciona perfectamente, luego de subir la aplicacion a heroku (le he creado una pagina estatica como root home) y conectarme a la direccion la url/grahpql o graphiql pareciera ser que esta no esta instalada en la aplicacion que se subio (por interfaz web) mi routes file es el siguiente:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  if Rails.env.development?
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  end

  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
  mount ActionCable.server, at: '/cable'

  root 'static_pages#home'

end
```

No habra algun tipo de modificacion en el condicional que llama al env development o algo por el estilo que me identifique una ruta para produccion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se recomienda habilitar `graphiql` solo en entorno de desarrollo principalmente por el poder que eventualmente puede tener la interfaz sobre tus datos de producción.
Si de todas formas quieres habilitarlo, borrando la condición `if Rails.env.development?` debería ser suficiente, o si quieres habilitarlo únicamente en dev/prod, prueba con

```
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production? 
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  end
```

fijándote que la gema también se encuentre habilitada para ambos entornos en tu `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'graphiql-rails', '1.7.0', group: [:development, :production]
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, osea que para production no deberia entrar con url/graphql? he puesto ese condicional pero aun asi me envia el trace de heroku un error cuando le hago deploy  NameError: uninitialized constant GraphiQL. Me tira el error por esa linea:
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"mount

Comment: @ricardoleivasikic pensé que tu problema era que no podías acceder a la ruta simplemente, no que te arrojaba un error ya que no lo agregaste a tu pregunta. Podrías revisar que `graphiql-rails` se encuentre en el grupo adecuado de tu `Gemfile`, en caso que la tengas en un grupo en particular.

Comment: gracias por la printa respuesta,  el error se me origino cuando agregue rails.env.production? pero ademas pense en borrar ese condicional. aun asi tendria que funcionar la ruta si la pruebo en postman no? url/graphql

Comment: Si no funciona con tu browser, no hay razón para que si funcione con postman. ¿probaste lo de revisar tu Gemfile?

Comment: hola, si revise la gemfile y tengo:
gem 'graphql', '1.9.17'
gem 'graphiql-rails', '1.7.0', group: :development
lo que si es raro obviamente que si no coloco la condicional me genera el deploy heroku pero con el error de graphiql, entre parentesis la app funciona en local con graph

Comment: Cambia en tu Gemfile entonces a `gem 'graphiql-rails', '1.7.0', group: [:development, :production]`. Si tienes habilitada la gema solo a funcionar para dev, no hay forma que se cargue para producción.

Comment: vale man si me falto eso ahora solo tengo que arreglar un bug jaja me conecta a graphi pero me salta un error : Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different, ahi estoy viendo si es porque debo agregar resolutions a package.json